# Parallel.Foreach taking more time than normal foreach in c#

Tags: c#

Below is code which I am using in Parrllel.Foreach. But it is taking same time as normal foreach. Here filingDataItems,  nonPeriodic, periodiccells are data tables. Does this happening due to data tables?

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(tempfilingReferences, T2 =>
            {                             
                    Filing f = new Filing(
                                         T2.Id,
                                         T2.DocumentPeriod,
                                         T2.FilingDate,
                                         T2.VersionId,
                                         T2.DocumentId,
                                         T2.PrimaryPeriodTypeId,
                                         T2.IssuedAsPreliminaryFlag,
                                         T2.IssuedAsAmendmentFlag,
                                         T2.FilingDetails,
                                         T2.CompanyId,
                                 GetFilingDataItems(filingDataItems, T2.Id, nonPeriodic, periodiccells, filingToPeriodList, DPTPList, posList),
                                 GetPeriods(filingToPeriodList, periodInfoList, T2.Id),
                                 GetFilingToPeriods(filingToPeriodList, T2.Id),
                                         true,
                                         false,
                                         AuditedDataType.Financials,
                                         T2.FilingTypeList
                               );


                        lock (filingListnew)
                        {
                                filingListnew.Add(f);
                        }
            });
```

Comment: You have all the overhead of setting up a parallel loop, but because you are locking to do the actual work, you have few of the benefits. Result = performance decrease.

Comment: @MatthewWatson said it all.

Comment: Things have to actually be parallizable to benefit here, you dont get a magic speed increase just by doing `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: _"Does this happening due to data tables?"_ - we don't know, you didn't show that code. Apart from the `lock()`, the methods `GetFilingDataItems()`, `GetPeriods()` and `GetFilingToPeriods()` may very well be slower when called in parallel.

Comment: Also note, that for small data sources or simple operations inside the loop the overhead of running stuff in parallel can overshadow the performance benefit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are locking in the parallel part. 
So you wait in each thread for the active thread to remove the lock. 
So this is nearly the same as the sequencial foreach.

For example:

**Parallel.Foreach:**

*Cycle1*

Thread1: filingListnew.Add(Object1);

Thread2: locked

Thread3: locked

Thread4: locked

*Cycle2*

Thread1: locked

Thread2: filingListnew.Add(Object2);

Thread3: locked

Thread4: locked

*Cycle3*
...

**"Normal" foreach:**

*Cycle1*

Main Thread: filingListnew.Add(Object1);

*Cycle2*

Main Thread: filingListnew.Add(Object2);

*Cycle3*
...

As you can see in the examples you cannot gain performance the way you are using ParallelForeach.

Comment: See Dmitry's answer, but to address that specific question: use concurrent collections (works best if you don't need it to be in any specific order).

Comment: If you just did the ParallelForeach for not blocking the main thread a long time you can move the whole foreach into an other thread

Answer (score 2):

You'd rather not *lock at each step*, but try using *LINQ*:

```
  filingListnew.AddRange(tempfilingReference
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(T2 => new Filing(...)));
```

If you have *to preserve the order* :

```
  filingListnew.AddRange(tempfilingReference
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(T2 => new Filing(...)));
```

You may find useful *to create the list*, not adding to it:

```
  filingListnew = tempfilingReference
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(T2 => new Filing(...)))
    .ToList();
```

Linq is easy to switch between sequential/parallel just comment out *AsParallel()* (or put *AsSequential()*)